# How to scale a rectangles width around a fixed point with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a splitscreen, and on the bottom I want to have a bar that goes either in the left side or the right side, but the starting point is always in the center.

If it would be static, it would be no problem, but i want to make it dynamic. So it can be that it goes from the left side to the right side, passing a point where the width is 0.

My current approach was:

```
#bar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px; /*this will be dynamic*/
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

but the problem is, width can't have a negative value, otherwise i could just flip it to the other side.

What can i do?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you better approach js/jquery for dynamic things rather than css.

Comment: Please post your markup, and if possible a minimal working example in jsFiddle or similar. Without knowing the markup of your project, we cannot help. It sounds like something that can be easily achieved in CSS using absolute and relative positioning, but of course we can't tell really without seeing more.

Answer (score -1):

I would try it this way:

- Wrap the bar inside an element which has 50% width.
- If you want the bar on the left, add class `left` to the wrapper which sets the left margin of the bar inside to `auto`. This makes the bar jump to right, inside the wrapper, so the end of the bar will be at the center.
- If you want the bar on the right, add class `right` to the wrapper,  which just sets the left margin of the bar to 50%, making it start at the center

So if you are setting the bar's width dynamically, you just have to swap `left` and `right` class on the wrapper whether the desired width is positive or negative, and set the width always to the absolute value.

```css
.bar {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

.bar-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}

.bar-wrapper.left .bar {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.bar-wrapper.right {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-wrapper left">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="bar-wrapper right">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: *Thank you* for the downvote, unknown user! It's really *constructive and motivating*. Would you be so kind to suggest me how can I improve my answer or point out what mistakes I made to deserve your downvote?